# How to open a text file in C

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

In my text file, there are random binary numbers written in a
10x10 matrix.
I want to print them in C exactly as they appear in the text file.
So I made my code like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char number[100];
    FILE *mz = fopen("maze.txt", "r");

    while (!feof(mz)) {
        fscanf(mz, "%s", number);
        printf("%s\n", number);
    }
    fclose(mz);
}
```

But the outputs were 100x1 matrix, not 10x10.
What should I do to print an ordinary 10x10 matrix?

Comment: You also need to read [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: ... and you need to check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly. Also please [edit] and show the verbatim `maze.txt`, as properly formatted text. If the file is really long (>15 lines or so) just show the first 15 lines.

Comment: What does "binary numbers written in 10x10 matrix" mean? You read strings, not numbers. Do you have a 10 digits without spaces per line? Or 10 numbers with spaces? Please edit the question to include the input file and your output as formatted text.

Comment: Can you post an example of the text file contents are the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

**`"%s"` does not read a *line***

`"%s"` skips leading whites space and then reads an unlimited number of non-white-space characters.

If the *line* of file input has spaces in it, the line, as a whole, will not get read as one *string*.

Use `fgets()` to read a line into a string.

**`while (!feof(mz))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)**

Do not do this.

**Do not read with `"%s"` without a *width* limit**

`"%s"` without a *width* is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

---

Suggested fix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINE_LENGTH 100

int main(void) {
  FILE* mz = fopen("maze.txt", "r");

  // Did open succeed?
  if (mz) {   
    char number[LINE_LENGTH*2];  // Use 2x the max amount expected.
    while (fgets(number, sizeof number, mz)) {
      printf("%s", number);
    }
    fclose(mz);
  }
}
```